# Python - how do I create a new decorated function that takes arguments?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I've read over this great post: [How to make a chain of function decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python)

I decided to fiddle around with it and I'm taking this block from it:

```
# It’s not black magic, you just have to let the wrapper 
# pass the argument:

def a_decorator_passing_arguments(function_to_decorate):
    def a_wrapper_accepting_arguments(arg1, arg2):
        print "I got args! Look:", arg1, arg2
        function_to_decorate(arg1, arg2)
    return a_wrapper_accepting_arguments

# Since when you are calling the function returned by the decorator, you are
# calling the wrapper, passing arguments to the wrapper will let it pass them to 
# the decorated function

@a_decorator_passing_arguments
def print_full_name(first_name, last_name):
    print "My name is", first_name, last_name

print_full_name("Peter", "Venkman")
# outputs:
#I got args! Look: Peter Venkman
#My name is Peter Venkman
```

What if, instead of just renaming the decorated `print_full_name(first_name, last_name)` as itself, I wanted to save the decorated version as a different function name, like `decorated_print_full_name(first_name, last_name)`? Basically, I'm more curious as to how I change the code so I ***DON'T*** use the `@a_decorator_passing_arguments` shortcut.

I rewrote the above (for Python 3):

```
def a_decorator_passing_arguments(function_to_decorate):
    def a_wrapper_accepting_arguments(arg1, arg2):
        print("I got args! Look:", arg1, arg2)
        function_to_decorate(arg1, arg2)
    return a_wrapper_accepting_arguments

#@a_decorator_passing_arguments
def print_full_name(first_name, last_name):
    print("My name is", first_name, last_name)

decorated_print_full_name = a_decorator_passing_arguments(print_full_name(first_name, last_name))

decorated_print_full_name("Peter", "Venkman")
```

but Python complains that `first_name` is not defined in line 11. I'm still new to Python so forgive me if I missed something very obvious here.

Comment: don't pass `first_name` and `last_name` on line 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with:

```
decorated_print_full_name = a_decorator_passing_arguments(print_full_name)
```

Comment: Yep, I'm an idiot. I had to pass the function as a object, not as a call to it. Thank you!

Comment: If it hadn't failed there, it would latter when the wrapper attempts to call `None(arg1, arg2)`.